# Querying The Cancer Genome Atlas (TCGA) for gene expression

Tags: genome, database, gene-expression, cancer

The UCI gene expression cancer RNA-Seq ​dataset (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/gene+expression+cancer+RNA-Seq) consists of 5 types of cancers (BRCA, KIRC, LUAD, COAD, PRAD) and gene expression levels of 20,531 genes for 801 samples. The dataset looks like this:

[image: gene expression UCI dataset]

How to query in The Cancer Genome Atlas (TCGA) to create an updated version of this dataset?

I've done the following [query](https://portal.gdc.cancer.gov/&searchTableTab=files).

[image: same query in visual form]

Is the given query and the UCI dataset equivalent? If not, how to query properly?

P.S.: I'm a CS student; do not have any biology background.

Comment: Not quite what I was hoping for the query rather than the raw link ... Anyway I guess I wasn't clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, your query above is selecting for breast cancer samples (TCGA-BRCA) only. The original dataset seems to contain 4 other cancer types.

The link you provided has a link to https://www.synapse.org/#!Synapse:syn4301332 and by looking at filenames of the 14 files there, I can tell that there are different types of data: miRNA expression, gene expression, methylation, ... And your query is limited to gene expression only. I am not even sure if you can use just a single query to fetch all of the 14 data files, you might need to use multiple queries.

If you are familiar with R, I would recommend [TCGABiolinks](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/TCGAbiolinks.html), it will abstract away a lot of otherwise annoying manual steps. Apparently you can also use Python retrieve TCGA data:https://docs.gdc.cancer.gov/API/Users_Guide/Python_Examples/

Comment: I've added an image of the UCI dataset. I just need to perform a query that returns similar kind of gene expression level tabular data. 

As the query only returns TCGA-BRCA data only, will replicating the query for other four types create similar (biologically equivalent and meaningful) kind of dataset?

Comment: Yes, you can change the cancer type and re-use the query but my main concern is the type of data that this query would return. Your query fetches count data via the `HTSeq - Counts` filter but in the posted image, there are floats instead of integers (gene counts), this can be normalized data. If I remember correctly, HTSeq-Counts should be returning actual counts, so integers.